# Why is my XPath selecting nothing?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

My XML file

```
<classifications>
  <classification sequence="1">
    <classification-scheme office="" scheme="CS" />
    <section>G</section>
    <class>01</class>
    <subclass>R</subclass>
    <main-group>33</main-group>
    <subgroup>365</subgroup>
    <classification-value>I</classification-value>
  </classification>
  <classification sequence="2">
    <classification-scheme office="" scheme="CS" />
    <section>G</section>
    <class>01</class>
    <subclass>R</subclass>
    <main-group>33</main-group>
    <subgroup>3415</subgroup>
    <classification-value>A</classification-value>
  </classification>
  <classification sequence="1">
    <classification-scheme office="US" scheme="UC" />
    <classification-symbol>324/300</classification-symbol>
  </classification>
  <classification sequence="2">
    <classification-scheme office="US" scheme="UC" />
    <classification-symbol>324/307</classification-symbol>
  </classification>          
</classifications>
```

I want to parse the value with following condition
required all the `classification-symbol` element value along with condition `office="US"`

I tried with below XPath,

```
NodeList usClassification = (NodeList)xPath.compile("//classifications//classification//classification-scheme[@office=\"US\"]//classification-symbol//text()").evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

but I'm getting an empty result set,

```
System.out.println(usClassification.getLength()); //its becomes zero
```

Comment: Try to avoid indiscriminate use of "//" in this way. It's a lazy habit and when you do it four times in the same path it can badly hurt performance, especially if your source document is large.

Comment: Right, especially since the functional difference between `//` (which selects descendants) and `/` (which selects immediate children) is irrelevant for your XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This XPath (written on two lines to ease readability),

```
/classifications/classification[classification-scheme/@office='US']
                /classification-symbol/text()
```

will select the `classification-symbol` text of the `classification` elements with `classification-scheme` `@office` attribute value equal to `US`:

```
324/300
324/307
```

as requested.

Answer (score 3):

`classification-symbol` is not a child of `classification-scheme` - they are *siblings*. Use [`following-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) axis to get from "scheme" to "symbol" instead:

```
//classifications/classification/classification-scheme[@office=\"US\"]/following-sibling::classification-symbol/text()
```

Comment: This is an alternative approach that works equally well (+1).